# Proxy mail to different smtp server with Postfix

Tags: postfix, proxy, forwarding

How can I forward (or proxy) mail to different smtp servers depending on the To address?

I've got one machine with an SMTP (postfix) server listening on port 25. I want to use Lamson (http://lamsonproject.org/) to handle some incoming mail and some mail I want to have postfix to handle.

My idea is to setup Lamson to listen on a different port, let's say localhost:10025. I then setup postfix to catch all mail by listening on port 25.

How do I configure Postfix to proxy certain mail to Lamson on 10025 and handle all other mail itself?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Postfix is extremely flexible (and therefore, complex) in its configuration, so there are various ways to achieve this. The simplest way would probably be to use a [`transport(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) table.

First, enable the use of a transport table in postfix:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

You'll also have to make sure that Postfix accepts mails for the addresses that will be handled by Lamson. Have a look at [`permit_auth_destination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_auth_destination) for the rules Postfix will apply to determine valid recipient addresses. For the following example, assuming "example.com" is a domain not otherwise known to Postfix, it's probably easiest to simply add it as relay domain:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    relay_domains = example.com
```

Then, create an appropriate table. E.g. to redirect all mail for the domain "example.com" as well as mail for "user@mydomain.org" to your local Lamson listening at port 10025:

```
/etc/postfix/transport:
    example.com          smtp:127.0.0.1:10025
    user@mydomain.org    smtp:127.0.0.1:10025
```

After that (and then once after every update to the transport table file) don't forget to run:

```
$ postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

This should get you going. Be sure to read the [`transport(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) man page, which will give you more ideas on how to use this powerful facility.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I'm still having problems with getting the mail forwarded after following your instructions. I'm getting NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from {my-mail-relay} Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah yes, you'll also have to make sure, that Postfix accepts mail to be relayed towards example.com (as Postfix is now acting as a relay for Lamson). If your Postfix is mainly serving another domain, the easiest way to achieve this is adding the "Lamson domain" to `relay_domains`. I updated to answer to incorporate this.

Comment: Thanks, after following your steps, I was still having some problems getting postfix to recognize localhost as a valid host. I ran the command postconf -e 'smtp_host_lookup = dns, native' and that solved my problem, postfix is now forwarding the mail I want to Lamson.

Comment: Good to hear that it works. Instead of changing `smtp_host_lookup`, you could also use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. I've updated the answer to accommodate that improvement.