# Send subdomain mail to script/process with postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am trying to do some special mail processing beyond what my mail client's rules/filters can handle (interact with a webservice API).  Since I know Python, I am looking at using [Lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/) to process the e-mails.  As I was going through the setup I realized that my virtual private server already had a mail server listening on port 25, postfix.  This is a rather simple Ubuntu box and I believe postfix was installed as part of my other packages (Apache, MySQL, MySQL, Munin).

Rather than muck around with Postfix, I'd like to have mail addressed to *@sub.example.com handled by my Lamson listener.  Since Postfix controls port 25, what are my options?  Is there a way I can configure Postfix to forward everything addressed to sub.example.com to my Lamson project listening on localhost:2525 (or other suitable port) for processing?  If so, what configuration changes will be required to do so?  Other suitable approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a transport to deliver mail to Lamson. There is a [previous post](https://serverfault.com/questions/67134/proxy-mail-to-different-smtp-server-with-postfix) which could help you.

Comment: Wow, my search skills failed me.  Thanks for the tip!